# Backup whole site through php script

Tags: php, backup

I have a site which is developed in codeigniter.

I want to know how can I backup my site [folders, files etc] through php.

Comment: when i am using cp command from Linux prompt

Comment: Got a cool code for backing up the files and DB(Not tested)
http://codedevelopr.com/articles/bash-wordpress-backup-script/

Answer (score 10):

You could use Shel Exec : http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

What this allows you to do is run shell commands via a php script.

```
<?php
function backup()
 {
  shell_exec("tar -cvf batckup.tar.gz /var/www/* ");
 }

backup();
?>
```

The script needs permissions so chmod it.

This this would be a rough way to do it. Another would be to set up a cronjob..

simple script :

```
   #!/bin/bash

  cd /www/var/
  tar zcf /home/sh/backup-`date +%Y%m%d`.tar.gz backup
```

Be sure to add the executable permission to the script:

```
chmod +x /home/sh/backup.sh
```

Then add the relevant crontab entry with the crontab -e command:

```
0 13 * * 2 /home/sh/backup.sh
```

This is a weekly backup you can look here for time formats http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm

Then you are left with a backup :

```
backup-20110719.tar.gz
```

For your databases as mentioned

```
   15 2 * * * root mysqldump -u root -pPASSWORD --all-databases | gzip >    /home/backup/databaseBackup_`data ' %m-%d-%Y'`.sql.gz
```

Comment: Have added the second cron for database

Answer (score 3):

You have to backup:

1. Website files
2. Database

There is a solution for this: http://www.starkinfotech.com/php-script-to-take-a-backup-of-your-site-and-database/

Comment: Thats quite a nice tutorial actually. Very clear and concise!

Comment: The provided link is now broken.